# Powershell variable will not iterate, value is empty

Tags: powershell, azure

The following code generates a list:

```
    $users = Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $resource_group -SubscriptionId $subscription_id |
Select-Object -Property DnsPrefix, KubernetesVersion, Location, Name, ResourceGroupName, @{e = { $_.Tags.creator | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json }; l = 'Tags' } |
Sort-Object -Descending Creator |
ForEach-Object {
    new-object psobject -Property @{
        AzurePortalFQDN         = $_.AzurePortalFQDN
        DnsPrefix               = $_.DnsPrefix
        Fqdn                    = $_.Fqdn
        Id                      = $_.Id
        KubernetesVersion       = $_.KubernetesVersion
        Location                = $_.Location
        Name                    = $_.Name
        NodeResourceGroup       = $_.NodeResourceGroup
        ProvisioningState       = $_.ProvisioningState
        ResourceGroupName       = $_.ResourceGroupName
        ServicePrincipalProfile = $_.ServicePrincipalProfile
        Creator                 = if ($_.Tags) { $_.Tags } else { "zNo Creator Found" }
    }
} |
Select-Object -Property Creator |
Where-Object {$_.Creator -ne "zNo Creator Found"} |
Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

When I try to iterate through the list the $users variable is empty in the foreach and $user never gets populate

```
    foreach ($user in $users) {
    Write-Output $user
    $Output = Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $resource_group -SubscriptionId $subscription_id |
    Select-Object -Property DnsPrefix, KubernetesVersion, Location, Name, ResourceGroupName, @{e = { $_.Tags.creator | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json }; l = 'Tags' } |
    Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Tags.creator  -like $user} |
    Sort-Object -Descending Creator |
    ForEach-Object {
        new-object psobject -Property @{
            AzurePortalFQDN         = $_.AzurePortalFQDN
            DnsPrefix               = $_.DnsPrefix
            Fqdn                    = $_.Fqdn
            Id                      = $_.Id
            KubernetesVersion       = $_.KubernetesVersion
            Location                = $_.Location
            Name                    = $_.Name
            NodeResourceGroup       = $_.NodeResourceGroup
            ProvisioningState       = $_.ProvisioningState
            ResourceGroupName       = $_.ResourceGroupName
            ServicePrincipalProfile = $_.ServicePrincipalProfile
            Creator                 = if ($_.Tags) { $_.Tags } else { "zNo Creator Found" }
        }
    }

    Write-Output $Output
```

Could someone point me to why I can Write-Output $users and see the users but foreach cannot iterate over the same?

Comment: Don't `Format-Table` when creating your `$users` array. Remove this and try again.

Comment: Thank you, you should of responded as an answer to get credit!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [jfrmilner](https://superuser.com/users/182081/jfrmilner) was correct. Removing `Format-Table` solved the issue.